# How to do a clean installation of Windows 10 while keeping BitLocker enabled?

Tags: windows, windows-10, encryption, bitlocker, cryptography

I didn't want to have to disable the bitlocker to format the PC, because that would definitely make it possible to recover data that has not been rewritten, and I value the security and privacy of my information, how can I keep my data safe and non-recoverable after a clean installation? I usually when I did a clean installation and did not use Bitlocker, I simply connected the hard disk with the windows installation, accessed the diskpart and cleaned the entire disk drive that I would install windows on, but I started using Bitlocker and not I know how to proceed to maintain the security of the deleted data and doing a clean installation at the same time, without having to disable the bitlocker.

Comment: You cannot, Clean install will wipe the partition, once installed re-enble bitlocker.

Comment: You don’t; You can Reset Windows 10; The alternative is to delete all partitions on the disk then install Windows.